# How to Customize the convolution operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to perform a customize convolution operation in tensorflow using a 2x2 filter. The operation is like if we have a filter having 2 channels `[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]` and the image is like in 2 channels `[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]` the output should be like `output = [[26,40],[58,80]]`. This is output because `output[0][0] = 1 * 1 + 5 * 5, output[0][1]=2 * 2 + 5 * 5, output[1][0]=3 * 3 + 7 * 7, output[1][1]= 4 * 4 + 8 * 8`. Basically what we are doing here is we are multiplying the weights of image and weights of channel in one row and column and then adding up something like 1x1 convolution.

Comment: Check. https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/subclassing_conv_layers/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use this function **keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), ..)** where filters = (your 2 channel filter) and kernel_size = (2x2). If you want an in detail explanation of the function arguments, you can check it [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/). The rest will be defaulted. The manual change you have to do has been mentioned in this comment.